# how to get the array value if particular value is matched in whole array value

Tags: php, arrays

This is array output

```
 Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 1
    [menu_name] => Dashboard
    [read_or_edit] => E
    [active_inactive] => A )
  [1] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 2
    [menu_name] => Orders-View Orders
    [read_or_edit] => E [active_inactive] => A )
  [2] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 3
    [menu_name] => Orders-Sales Report
    [read_or_edit] => E
    [active_inactive] => A )
)
```

In that I just save **Dashboard** into on variable like `$pagename=Dashboard`, after that I use array search with my `$pagename` into whole array value.

Now how can I get that particular zero th key array value using match of dashboard?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I have reformatted your code block as it was on a single line and largely unreadable, please review [the link editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information about formatting your posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fine_data=Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 1
    [menu_name] => Dashboard
    [read_or_edit] => E
    [active_inactive] => A )
  [1] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 2
    [menu_name] => Orders-View Orders
    [read_or_edit] => E [active_inactive] => A )
  [2] => Array (
    [menu_id] => 3
    [menu_name] => Orders-Sales Report
    [read_or_edit] => E
    [active_inactive] => A )
)

$key = array_search($page_name, array_column($fine_data, 'menu_name'));
foreach ($fine_data as $key_final => $value) {
if($key_final==$key)
{
$acess=$value->read_or_edit;
//youo can get all value like an above
}
}
echo $acess;
```